# Nessus Vulnerability 35291 Weak Hashing Algorithm :383 HP OpenView

Tags: openssl, ssl

I got the Nessus Vulnerability 35291 Weak Hashing Algorithm on Port 383 - It's HP OpenView Agent - and I don't get any idea to close this.

I already updated the Agent to the newest version, which closed some vulnerabilities, but this is still open.

The Agent is Using SHA-1 and must be using at least SHA-2.

Has anyone solved this problem in past?

Thanks.